# Drawing all planes passing through two given points in a cube

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

Is there a smarter way to find a collection of possible planes passing through 2 given points `P` on `ABFE` and `Q` on `DCGH` such that we can see that the point `R` is the intersection of `PQ` and the common line between `ABCD` and each of the planes in question?

If the above rewording is not clear enough, just animate the cross section of *ALL* possible planes passing through the `PQ` in the given cube.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
% first frame
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-3)(13,14)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,0,135,180}](0,0){A}(10,0){B}(12,3){C}(2,3){D}(0,10){E}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle={0,0,135}]{A}{E}{B,C,D}[F,G,H]
    \psline(E)(H)(G)(C)(B)(F)(E)(A)(B)
    \psline(F)(G)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](H)(D)(C)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)
    % Extra
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,-90}](1,9){P}(7,-2){Q}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=180,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{A}{B}{P}
    \pstTranslation[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{B}{A}{Q}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=180]{A}{E}{P}{P'}{X}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=180]{D}{H}{Q}{Q'}{Y}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle={0}]{A}{B}{X,Y}
        \pstInterLL[PosAngle=180]{X}{Y}{A}{D}{Z}
        \pstTranslation[PosAngle=0]{D}{C}{Z}
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.25](X)(X')(Y')(Y)
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,opacity=0.25](A)(B)(C)(D)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](Z)(Z')
    \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](P)(Q)
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=0]{P}{Q}{Z}{Z'}{R}
\end{pspicture}


% second frame
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-3)(13,14)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,0,135,180}](0,0){A}(10,0){B}(12,3){C}(2,3){D}(0,10){E}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle={0,0,135}]{A}{E}{B,C,D}[F,G,H]
    \psline(E)(H)(G)(C)(B)(F)(E)(A)(B)
    \psline(F)(G)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](H)(D)(C)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)
    % Extra
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,-90}](1,9){P}(7,-2){Q}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=180,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{E}{A}{P}
    \pstTranslation[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{B}{F}{Q}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=-90]{A}{B}{P}{P'}{X}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=45]{C}{D}{Q}{Q'}{Y}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle={90}]{A}{E}{X,Y}
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.25](X)(X')(Y')(Y)
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,opacity=0.25](A)(B)(C)(D)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](X)(Y)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](P)(Q)
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=0]{P}{Q}{X}{Y}{R}
\end{pspicture}

% third frame
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-3)(13,14)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,0,0,135,180}](0,0){A}(10,0){B}(12,3){C}(2,3){D}(0,10){E}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle={0,0,135}]{A}{E}{B,C,D}[F,G,H]
    \psline(E)(H)(G)(C)(B)(F)(E)(A)(B)
    \psline(F)(G)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](H)(D)(C)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(D)
    % Extra
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,-90}](1,9){P}(7,-2){Q}
    \pstTranslation[PosAngle=180,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{E}{H}{P}
    \pstTranslation[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{C}{B}{Q}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=-90]{A}{B}{P}{Q'}{X}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=45]{C}{D}{Q}{P'}{Y}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=-90]{E}{F}{P}{Q'}{X'}
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=45]{H}{G}{Q}{P'}{Y'}
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,opacity=0.25](X)(X')(Y')(Y)
    \pspolygon[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,opacity=0.25](A)(B)(C)(D)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](X)(Y)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](P)(Q)
    \pstInterLL[PosAngle=0]{P}{Q}{X}{Y}{R}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand how this is a TeX question....

Comment: I have made an attempt to modify the question to make it more likely answerers will give you what you are looking for. Feel free to reverse my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may not do an animation and just use a plane with a nontrivial opacity such that one can see that the dashed red line hits the plane. My take is that you want to

> visually prove the point R is the common point of ABCD and PQ

because this is what is written in the question. If that's not what the question is about, consider editing it to make it clearer. (Sorry, I have quit pstricks a while ago, but I am sure you will be able to redo this with pstricks.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
\newcounter{coord}
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{200} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3,bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}] 
 \foreach \Z in {-1,1}
 {\foreach \Y in {-1,1}
  {\foreach \X in {-1,1} 
   {\stepcounter{coord}
   \path (\Y*\X,-1*\Y,\Z) coordinate (\Alph{coord})  -- ++ (0.2*\Y*\X,0,0) 
  node{$\Alph{coord}$} ;}}}
 \fill[cyan,opacity=0.5] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
 \draw[dashed] (A) -- (D) -- (C) (D) -- (H);  
 \draw (E) -- (F)  -- (G) -- (H) -- (E) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (G) (B) -- (F);
 \node[bullet,label=left:$P$] (P) at (1,0,0.5){};
 \node[bullet,label=above right:$R$] (R) at (1/3,0,-1){};
 \draw[red,dashed,thick] (P) -- (R)
     node[pos=1.5,black,bullet,label={[black]below:$Q$}] (Q){}; 
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \draw[red,dashed,thick] (R) -- (Q);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just want to rotate a plane, this can be done, of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc} 
\newcounter{coord}
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{200} 
\foreach \Angle in {5,10,...,180}
{\setcounter{coord}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3,bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}] 
 \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box]
  (-2,-2) rectangle (1.5,1.8);
 \foreach \Z in {-1,1}
 {\foreach \Y in {-1,1}
  {\foreach \X in {-1,1} 
   {\stepcounter{coord}
   \path (\Y*\X,-1*\Y,\Z) coordinate (\Alph{coord})  -- ++ (0.2*\Y*\X,0,0) 
  node{$\Alph{coord}$} ;}}}
 \fill[cyan,opacity=0.5] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
 \draw[dashed] (A) -- (D) -- (C) (D) -- (H);  
 \draw (E) -- (F)  -- (G) -- (H) -- (E) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (G) (B) -- (F);
 \node[bullet,label=left:$P$] (P) at (1,0,0.5){};
 \node[bullet,label=above right:$R$] (R) at (1/3,0,-1){};
 \draw[red,dashed,thick] (P) -- (R)
     node[pos=1.5,black,bullet,label={[black]below:$Q$}] (Q){}; 
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \draw[red,dashed,thick] (R) -- (Q);
    \fill[opacity=0.3,red!40] 
    ($(R)+({cos(\Angle)},{sin(\Angle)},0)$) -- 
    ($(R)+({cos(\Angle+180)},{sin(\Angle+180)},0)$) --
    ($(P)+({cos(\Angle+180)},{sin(\Angle+180)},0)$) -- 
    ($(P)+({cos(\Angle)},{sin(\Angle)},0)$) -- cycle;   
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And cropped planes. I stop here. I do believe I answered the original question. If you disagree, I respect this opinion, but I am not willing to go into another iteration.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,intersections} 
\newcounter{coord}
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{200} 
\foreach \Angle in {5,10,...,180}
{\setcounter{coord}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3,bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}] 
 \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box]
  (-2,-2) rectangle (1.5,1.8);
 \foreach \Z in {-1,1}
 {\foreach \Y in {-1,1}
  {\foreach \X in {-1,1} 
   {\stepcounter{coord}
   \path (\Y*\X,-1*\Y,\Z) coordinate (\Alph{coord})  -- ++ (0.2*\Y*\X,0,0) 
  node{$\Alph{coord}$} ;}}}
 \fill[cyan,opacity=0.5] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
 \draw[dashed] (A) -- (D) -- (C) (D) -- (H);  
 \draw (E) -- (F)  -- (G) -- (H) -- (E) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (G) (B) -- (F);
 \node[bullet,label=left:$P$] (P) at (1/3,1,0.5){};
 \node[bullet,label=above right:$R$] (R) at (1/3,0,-1){};
 \draw[red,dashed,thick] (P) -- (R)
     node[pos=1.5,black,bullet,label={[black]below:$Q$}] (Q){}; 
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \draw[red,dashed,thick] (R) -- (Q);
    \begin{scope}[overlay]
     \path[name path=upper boundary]
      (1,1,0.5)--(1,-1,0.5) -- (-1,-1,0.5)--(-1,1,0.5)--cycle;
     \path[name path=lower boundary]
      (1,1,-1)--(-1,1,-1) -- (-1,-1,-1)--(1,-1,-1)--cycle;
     \path[name path=upper line]  %  ($(P)+({3*cos(\Angle)},{3*sin(\Angle)},0)$)
     (P)
     -- ($(P)+({3*cos(180+\Angle)},{3*sin(180+\Angle)},0)$);
     \path[name path=lower line]  
     ($(R)+({3*cos(\Angle)},{3*sin(\Angle)},0)$)-- ($(R)+({3*cos(180+\Angle)},{3*sin(180+\Angle)},0)$);
     \path[name intersections={of=upper boundary and upper line,name=Pint}];
     \path[name intersections={of=lower boundary and lower
     line,name=Rint}];
    \end{scope}
    \ifnum\Angle<60
     \draw[red,fill opacity=0.3,fill=red!40]  (P) -- (Pint-1) --
      (Rint-1) -- (Rint-2)   -- (1,1,0.5)-- cycle;
    \else
     \ifnum\Angle<110
     \draw[red,fill opacity=0.3,fill=red!40] (P) -- (Pint-1) -- (Rint-2) -- (Rint-1) -- cycle;
     \else
     \ifnum\Angle<150
      \draw[red,fill opacity=0.3,fill=red!40] (P) -- (Pint-1)
      --  (Rint-2)  -- (Rint-1)  -- cycle;
     \else
      \draw[red,fill opacity=0.3,fill=red!40] (P) -- (Pint-1)
      --  (Rint-2)  -- (Rint-1)  -- (-1,1,0.5) --cycle;
     \fi 
     \fi
    \fi
 \end{scope}
 \node at (0,0) {\Angle};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the collection of infinitely many planes passing through `PQ`?

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit These planes are IMHO not necessary to "visually prove the point R is the common point of ABCD and PQ".

Comment: The planes are required for my question.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit But not for my answer. ;-) And sorry to say that, but your screen shot is confusing precisely because below R the line seems to run in front of the plane.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit I added an animation....

Comment: Is it possible to trim the excessive part of the planes. The excessive parts are parts of the planes that are outside the cube.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit Sure. At which cartesian coordinates do you want P to sit. At the moment it is at `(1,0,0.5)`, i.e. at one of the faces of the cube.

Comment: `P` is on `ABFE` and `Q` is on `CDGH` as shown in my figure.

Comment: The cross section is not perfect because it does not cut the cube thoroughly.

Answer (score 5):

You do not to need to draw all this planes to make a visual proof. You need only one well chosen plane and some lines in it. For example the vertical plane that contains PQ intersect the front and the back faces in two vertical lines. These lines intersect the two bottom edges in X and Y. So the point R will be on the intersection of XY and PQ.

So the only thing that was missing in your drawing, IMO, was the auxiliary (vertical in this case) lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\def\qx{.7}\def\qy{-.3} % the coordinate of Q
\def\px{.3}\def\py{.7}  % the coordinate of P
\tikzstyle{every edge}=[draw,shorten <=-5mm,shorten >=-5mm]
\tikzstyle{*}=[insert path={coordinate(#1) node[scale=2]{.}}] % a (named) dot
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,z={(.4,.3)}]
    % the bottom plane
    \fill[blue,opacity=.2] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,0,0);
    % the auxiliary lines
    \draw[red,very thin]
      (\qx,\qy,1) edge (\qx,1,1) [*] node[right]{$Q$} coordinate(Q)
      (\qx,0,1) [*=QB] node[black,above right]{$Y$}
      (\qx,1,1) [*=QT]
      (\px,1,0) edge (\px,-0,0)
      (\px,\py,0) [*] node[left]{$P$} coordinate(P)
      (\px,0,0) [*=PB] node[black,above left]{$X$}
      (\px,1,0) [*=PT]
      (PT) edge (QT)
      (PB) edge (QB)
    ;
    % the line PQ with R on it
    \draw[red,densely dashed] (P) edge (Q) (intersection of P--Q and PB--QB)
      [*] node[below]{$R$};
    % the vertical plane
    \fill[yellow,opacity=.1,yscale=2] (PT) -- (QT) -- (QB) -- (PB);
    % the cube
    \draw
      (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0)
      (1,1,1)--(1,0,1)--(1,0,0)
      (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0)
    ;
    \draw[densely dashed]
      (0,0,1) -- (0,0,0) (0,0,1) -- (1,0,1) (0,0,1) -- (0,1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You just draw one plane, you need to draw others by rotating it about `PQ`.

Comment: I want to visually prove that the choice of plane passing through `PQ` does not matter to get `R`.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit sorry, but I don't get it. It's obvious that any plane that contains PQ will contain R, and so R will be on the line that is the  intersection of the bottom plane and the chosen plane. But you do not need a cube for this, the cube is only making this to look more complicated, IMO.

Comment: The problem is given as it is. We need to show that any planes passing through `PQ` can be chosen to get the point `R`. The complexity is the main problem. :-)

Comment: In this case probably you should show how you construct R from X,P and Q, where X is an arbitrary point on a bottom edge.